# Creating a method for settings of GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, methods, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have couple of components that each hold 4/5 lines of code regarding their settings in the GUI. so I thought it would be better if I create a method for those settings so they don't repeat for every component.

Here is my example code for one component:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

JButton browse = new JButton("Browse"); 

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.ipady=20;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.weightx=1;
c.gridheight=2;
c.insets = new Insets(5,-5,5,0);
panel.add(browse, c);
```

So is there any way to put these `c` lines, in a method? and is it a good practice at all?

Comment: *"So is there any way to put these c lines, in a method? and is it a good practice at all?"* Yes and yes.  You could use a [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) or a [Builder Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) depending on your needs and desire for future reusability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is there any way to put these c lines, in a method?

Yes

Create a method, this will either take a `GridBagConstraint` as a parameter and modify it or return a new instance of `GridBagConstraint`.  Which will depend on your needs; do you want to modify an existing constraint or create a brand new one

> and is it a good practice at all

Yes.  You could use a [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) or a [Builder Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) depending on your needs and desire for future reusability

Remember though, you can define basic properties for `GridBagConstraints` and modify it per component based on your needs, each component, when added to the container, will be assigned their own copy of the `GridBagConstraints`, so it's okay to use a single instance of `GridBagConstraints` over multiple components when establishing your UI